# Batch programing to search some file in sub folders

Tags: batch-file, search, directory, subdirectory

I have hundreds of csv files . csv files are stored in folders and sub ​​folders . I want to search fifty csv file whose file names have been determined , for example 1.csv , 2.csv , 3.csv , ... , 50.csv . very troublesome if I searched one by one using the Windows search tool . I would like if the files are found , save in the folder named FOUND . please help to overcome this problem by using the batch programming / bat ? thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of approaches one can take, depending on how much automation you require... To help you get started, you may want to look at [this](http://ss64.com/nt/) it helped me (and indeed continues to do so) when I started learning batch. Furthermore I will provide **one possible template** for achieving your objective, as I have interpreted it. Perhaps it is not the most elegant or efficient method, but it introduces a number of batch commands that you may or may not have encountered, which in turn may help you develop your own method.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo Please enter a drive letter:
set /p "drive=>"
echo Please enter a search string:
set /p "searchstring=>"
echo %searchstring%>search.txt

set /p search=<search.txt
set /a suffix=0
echo.>>search.txt

:LOOP
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("search.txt") do (
set /a suffix=suffix+1
set seq=%search% !suffix!
echo !seq!>>search.txt
)
if !suffix! leq 49 goto LOOP

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (search.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('dir /b /s /a-d %drive%:\"%%i.csv" 2^>nul') do (
    if not exist "%~dp0\found" md "%~dp0\found"
    move /y "%%j" "%~dp0\found\%%~nxj"
    )
)
pause
```

This is not intended as a definitive solution, though you may find it answers your original query/request. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another working solution for you..

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM First Set your directories input and output
SET InputDir=C:\Directory to your CSV files\
SET OutputDir=C:\Directory to your CSV files\FOUND

REM check if the FOUND directory exist, if not, then create it.
IF NOT EXIST OutputDir (
mkdir %OutputDir%
)

REM Grab a scan of the input directory and save it to a temporary file list.
Dir /a /b %InputDir%>"%OutputDir%\Found.txt"

REM Set the files you would like to find.
SET "File1=1.csv"
SET "File2=2.csv"
SET "File3=50.csv"

REM The loop, to process the matching file(s).
FOR %%A IN (%File1%,%File2%,%File3%) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq" %%B IN ("%OutputDir%\Found.txt") DO (
    IF %%A==%%B (
    copy "%InputDir%\%%A" "%OutputDir%\%%A"
    )
  )
)

REM Clean up the temp file list.
DEL "%OutputDir%\Found.txt"
```

Make note, I didn't add quotes to the Input and Output variables, but instead added quotes to the copy portion of the code to compensate for white spaces in your directory path. I tried to keep it simple, so you could follow the logic of how it processed what you are looking for, you can now modify this to your liking.. Have fun. Cheers!